# How to style a unicode character?

Tags: javascript, css, unicode

I would like to style the [unicode character DROPLET](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a7/index.htm) (), specifically change the blue color to something else.

```css
.red {
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<span class="red">DROPLET </span>
```

The `yellow` style is applied but not the color of the character (the text is correctly styled).

**Is styling any unicode glyph possible?**

Comment: You might want to use Icons instead, it's way easier to style and play with. I highly suggest [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/), but there is a ton of icons pack out there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

```css
.red {
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.red > span {
   filter: hue-rotate(180deg) saturate(10);
}
```

```html
<span class="red">DROPLET <span></span></span>
```

Or mix-blend-mode but this will also affect the background:

```css
.red {
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.red > span {
  filter:brightness(0); /* We make the icon black */
}
.red:before {
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   background:red;
   pointer-events:none;
   mix-blend-mode:lighten; /* this will make the icon red since red is more "light" than black*/
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<span class="red">DROPLET <span></span></span>
```

Comment: If you separate the character into its own span you can just apply a `color`. No need to complicate things.

Comment: @Paulie_D but color isn't working, this the main issue

Comment: Sure it does - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/YzzGdvo - Version 78.0.3904.63 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)

Comment: @Paulie_D it doesn't on Chrome (at least for me)

Comment: @Paulie_D: it does not either for me (Chrome) - this is what I tried in the question.

Comment: It does in my Chrome...it's basic CSS...the fact that it's a unicode character is irrelevant

Comment: @Paulie_D even in Firefox it doesn't work (using Windows) and unicode aren't always the same as simple character, you cannot change the coloration of emoji defined with unicde like you want.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I was about to say the same thing as Temani: it does not work in my FF either

Comment: It's not a browser thing, it only depends on the font used. If @Paulie's system defaults to a solid color font for emojis, then indeed they will see it colored as they authored it, if however they had a color emoji font as default for emojis (as it is in most OS by default), then they would have experienced the same issue). Which means that an other solution is to load a web-font that has these emoji as solid color.