# How can I change the tint of an emoji with CSS?

Tags: css, emoji

I would like to change the tint of an emoji, e.g. if I have a yellow smiley, I would like to change its color tone so that it appears red.

This very naïve approach does not work:

```css
.red-emoji {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-emoji">this text is red, but that emoji is not → </div>
```

I would like to achieve this:

[image: emoji tinted red]

I made this image with Photoshop by adding an adjustment layer, I hope modern CSS has something similar (filters or something) that I can use to achieve this.

Comment: yes there is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58450728/8620333 (filter and blend-mode)

Comment: @TemaniAfif the emoji here is used inside the text, neither filter not blend-mode will be able to modify that to the desired result. Using a combination of filters is able to somewhat change the color but not to the specific desired result. blend-mode only works on backgrounds.

Comment: @Luze you can wrap the emoji inside a span (like shown in the question I linked) and no, blend-mode doesn't work only on background (like shown in the question I linked too)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I didn't know this was possible, thank you.