# Why pseudo element looks different on different devices?

Tags: html, css

I used this code in my CSS file that included to my page, but some times appear in different appearance.
For example, color is white, but in some of the android devices render in red!

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked::after{
    position: relative !important;
    content: '✔' !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    font-size: 19px !important;
    margin: -9px 1px !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    vertical-align: top !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-family: Yekan !important;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: the character is the problem, the font isn't the same in all the devices

Comment: No, I added this font to my CSS and I checked with Arial font

Comment: maybe the font isn't loading

Comment: I use this font in another section and it's work well

Comment: What is the relation between font and color whether I used "white !important" in my css

Comment: some unicde character cannot be styled by color and this depend on the OS and the font, related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58450687/8620333

Comment: In that case, try adding `\FE0E` to the content.