# How to change SVG stroke color on mouse over when using an object

Tags: html, css, svg, sass, html-object

I am trying to make an svg image stroke color change when the mouse moves over the image. What I have now does not change the color of the stroke, and I am not sure why. If I manually change the stroke color through devtools it works fine.

I do notice that when I use an object to load an svg I get `#document` item in the inspector. Does that have any effect on why my color isn't changing when I mouse over the image?

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="">
    <object data="/images/icon.svg"></object>
  </a>
</li>
```

```
.nav-item {
    svg:hover {
        path {
            stroke: #da25e7;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Does that have any effect on why my color isn't changing when I mouse over the image?* --> yes. Using object is like using iframe, you cannot affect what is inside using outside CSS

Comment: So, then is there another way for me to change the color of the svg without imbedding the svg file into the page?

Comment: I don't think so unless you consider some workaround to similuate color changes like filter, mix blend mode, etc ... some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58450728/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I can directly put the style within the svg file. The downside to this is that it is used everywhere, and places that I don't want a hover effect with the image will still have one.

```html
<svg>
  <style>
    svg:hover path {stroke: #da25e7;}
  </style>
  <rect ...>...</rect>
</svg>
```

Then include the file:

```html
<object data="/images/icon.svg"></object>
```

Comment: add `pointer-events:none` to object where you don't want the hover effect

Comment: I assume you mean to the `object` tag?