# Coloring copy paste symbols and unicodes

Tags: css

as many of the copy paste symbols or unicode characters are colorless, is it possible to attain color? I tried to do with css, but doesn't affect.

I tried to do:

```
<label style="color:red;"></label>  
<label style="color:red !important;"></label> 
<label style="color:#f00;"></label>
```

Comment: will this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450687/how-to-style-a-unicode-character

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450687/how-to-style-a-unicode-character
Yes, Thank you  mixing css worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add use like this using **font-awesome Library**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>fa fa-link</h1>

<i class="fa fa-link"></i>
<i class="fa fa-link" style="font-size:24px; color: yellow;"></i>
<i class="fa fa-link" style="font-size:36px; color: green;"></i>
<i class="fa fa-link" style="font-size:36px; color: orange;"></i>
<i class="fa fa-link" style="font-size:48px;color:red"></i>
</body>
</html>
```